# Save As Button without confirmation

Tags: vba, excel

Hey I'm having a problem with the Save As Button I'm trying to make. It should always save under the same path with the same name and without confirmation. Here's the code I've got so far:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Application.EnableEvents = False

 Dim vFile
 Dim strDirectoryPath As String
  If SaveAsUI Then
vFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("C:\temp\Sample.xlsm", "Excel files (*.xlsm),*.xlsm")
If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then
 Cancel = True
 Application.EnableEvents = True
   Exit Sub  ' user cancelled
End If
strDirectoryPath = "C:\temp\"
If Dir(strDirectoryPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir strDirectoryPath

 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs vFile, FileFormat:=56
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 saveProcessStarted = False
 Cancel = True
 Exit Sub
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: And the problem/error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you do not want to see any dialogs when saving a workbook.

Try using the following code:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs vFile, FileFormat:=56
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```